# Mule FTP move file from one temp/work directory to another

Tags: ftp, mule

I have a scenario where I am inserting the data from FTP file into various systems. I have a couple of questions regarding FTP in Mule

-Is it possible to have a temp/work directory in FTP Inbound endpoint? The moveToDirectory works as a processed folder, I would like to move my source file into temp directory first and then have Mule download it.

-On success, the scenario demands, the original file to be moved from source/temp folder to success Folder. On an occurrence of an error, the original file should be moved to Failure Folder. Is it possible to only move and rename original file rather than storing the file in the payload and write it back in success or failure scenario?

Thanks,

Varada